# Menu Dead Link Command Does Not Work in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm trying to write a menu for a WP page and I seem to have it working except for one thing.  I'm basically copying and pasting from another project someone else in our department did.  The code I'm working from is below (sorry I don't know how to paste code in this forum):

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/bom_homepage_doc">Business Operations Manual</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/bom_preface_letter_doc">Preface</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/bom_preface_letter_doc">Letter from the Deputy</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/bom_preface_preface_doc">Preface</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/bom_preface_timeline_doc">Timeline</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The live output link is below.  Please note that the PREFACE is a "#" (dead link) which is correct as it just does the pull down menu.  Notice how there is an actual link href in there but somehow, on output, it switches to #.  You can see the live final code by looking at the source in browser, and here's the link:

http://www.ppi.noaa.gov/bom/

So here is my code (sorry I don't know how to paste code in this forum):

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide">Welcome</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_introduction">Introduction</a>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_types">Types</a>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_planning">Planning</a>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_1">References</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_1">1. Performance Measurement</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_2">2. Logic Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_3">3. Scenarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_4">4. Design Matrix</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_5">5. Additional Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Notice in REFERENCES I want that to be like the first example above, a "#" that just pulls down the drop down menu.  I pretty much set it up like the first example, where REFERENCES has the same href as the first sub link below it.  You'd think it would work because that's how the first example above is set up, but my result doesn't do the # but goes to the href page instead of #, which is not what I want.  Here's my link:

http://www.ppi.noaa.gov/program_evaluation_guide/

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Currently reference has a deadlink (#) there

Comment: You're right.  After I posted this, I found a solution and cleaned up the code.  I apologize for not posting on here sooner to let readers know that.  Thanks very much for your post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this and cleaned up the code too.  I want to post this for others in case they will find it useful:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_types">Types</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_planning">Planning</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">References</a>
    <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_1">1. Performance Measurement</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_2">2. Logic Models</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_3">3. Scenarios</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_4">4. Design Matrix</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/program_evaluation_guide_reference_5">5. Additional Resources</a></li>
</ul></li>
```